# Spring boot and LDAP with SHA512 password

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ldap

I'm writing a little application for use it as authentication server as microservice. (We are dividing an old monolithic app).

This app has to login through a LDAP server (which is protected by an username and password). And ever user password is stored as SHA512 hash. But I always get an "BAD CREDENTIALS" error

Here is my code

> WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin();

        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(ldapAuthProvider());
            auth.ldapAuthentication().passwordCompare().passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder()).passwordAttribute("userPassword");
            super.configure(auth);
        }


    public LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthProvider() {

        DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource("ldap://myldaphost:389/");
        contextSource.setUserDn("cn=myuser");
        contextSource.setPassword("mypassword");



        FilterBasedLdapUserSearch userSearch = new FilterBasedLdapUserSearch("", "(&amp;(cn={0})(estado=activo))", contextSource);


        BindAuthenticator bindAuthenticator = new BindAuthenticator(contextSource);
        bindAuthenticator.setUserSearch(userSearch);


        LdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new LdapAuthenticationProvider(bindAuthenticator);

        return provider;

    }
}
```

> pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-authenticating-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- tag::security[] -->
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
    <!-- end::security[] -->

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

> HomeController.java

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Welcome to the home page!";
    }

}
```

> applicationContext-security.xml from the OLD APP which currently works

```
<beans>


<!-- SECURITY ENABLED -->
<beans profile="security-enabled">
    <!-- Data  Data Base & LDAP-->      
    <bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean id="bindAuthenticator" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
                <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
                <property name="userSearch" ref="userSearch" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userSearch"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="(&amp;(cn={0})(estado=activo))" />
        <constructor-arg index="2" ref="contextSource" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="contextSource"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
        <constructor-arg value="myurl" />
        <property name="userDn" value="myuser" />
        <property name="password" value="mypassword" />
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved myself

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin();

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.ldapAuthentication().userSearchFilter("(cn={0})(estado=activo)").contextSource().url("ldap://myurl:389/")
                .managerDn("cn=myadmin").managerPassword("mypass");

    }

}
```